# Error while trying to export a pandas dataframe as an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm trying to send a pandas dataframe to C directory as a excel file

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,3,5],[2,4,6]],index=['a1','a2'], columns=['b1','b2','b3'])
df.to_excel('C:/df1.xlsx',sheet_name='data')
```

This code gives me an error message such as

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13136/2106016881.py in <module>
----> 1 df.to_excel('C:/df1.xlsx',sheet_name='data')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2282             inf_rep=inf_rep,
   2283         )
-> 2284         formatter.write(
   2285             excel_writer,
   2286             sheet_name=sheet_name,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    832             # error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'ExcelWriter' with abstract
    833             # attributes 'engine', 'save', 'supported_extensions' and 'write_cells'
--> 834             writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
    835                 writer, engine=engine, storage_options=storage_options
    836             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py in __init__(self, path, engine, date_format, datetime_format, mode, storage_options, if_sheet_exists, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
    189             raise ValueError("Append mode is not supported with xlsxwriter!")
    190 
--> 191         super().__init__(
    192             path,
    193             engine=engine,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path, engine, date_format, datetime_format, mode, storage_options, if_sheet_exists, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
    923         self.handles = IOHandles(cast(Buffer, path), compression={"copression": None})
    924         if not isinstance(path, ExcelWriter):
--> 925             self.handles = get_handle(
    926                 path, mode, storage_options=storage_options, is_text=False
    927             )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    708         else:
    709             # Binary mode
--> 710             handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
    711         handles.append(handle)
    712 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/df1.xlsx'
```

Not really sure where the problem is being caused
Can anyone help me how to solve this?

Comment: Most non-administrator Windows accounts can't write directly to 'C:/'. Try writing to your usual document or work folder.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the file is not open in your computer.

While it is open by another software, python cannot access it, therefore you get the `Permission denied` error.